# Iterator inside HTML and JQuery for initializing a JQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm using a range element in SemanticUI. Like most of the SemanticUI elements, these elements have to be initialized using a JQuery.

This is the HTML code I have:

```
$var_display = $_POST['display'];
$iterator = 0;
foreach ($var_display as $it) {
  $iterator += 1;
  echo '
    <span class="ui fluid large label">Range</span>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <form class="ui form">
      <div class="field">
        <div class="fields">
          <div class="twelve wide field">
            <div class="ui blue range" id=#range-'.$iterator.'></div>
          </div>
          <div class="four wide field">
            <div class="ui input"><input type="text" id="input-'.$iterator.'"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
  ';
}
```

I need to use a foreach because the user can select many options with a check box and based on the number of choices I have to create one range for each option.

This solution is working and I'm creating ranges and inputs with dynamic IDs. Right now I need to create is a foreach in a JQuery to initialize this elements.

I tried to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      $('#range-'+i).range({
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        start: 5,
        input: '#input-'+i
      });
    }
});
```

The number "40" in the iterator is just a random number.

**EDIT**: I tried setting with a class but if I use class instead of IDs when I change a value in one of the ranges every other range is changed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?
Anyway I think there's an error in your PHP

```
<div class="ui blue range" id=#range-'.$iterator.'></div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="ui blue range" id="range-'.$iterator.'"></div>
```

JS

```
$( "div[id^='range']" ).each(function(index){
   var range = $(this);
   var inputId = range.parent().next().find("input").attr("id");
   range.range({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    start: 5,
    input: inputId 
  });
});
```

Here's a fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/n28w0gaq/

Since you already now the input id that matches the range, it would be better this:

```
$( "div[id^='range']" ).each(function(index){
   $(this).range({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    start: 5,
    input: "input-" + index 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The JQuery is working now. The problem was indeed the # in the PHP. But the javascript you recommended is not working.

Comment: Awesome! Cheers!

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me this JS so I can understand why is not working?

Comment: Oops I didn't notice you said it doesn't work. Sure I can explain. The `$( "div[id^='range']" )` selector selects all the div with id starting with "range" so for example `<div id="range1"></div>` would match

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I know it's not working because I initialize these elements on `$(document).ready(function(){` so it's not finding any divs by the time it's initializing.

Comment: That's weird. When I do that the input's don't work: http://i.imgur.com/32e9dhE.png and when I try using the "40" it works: http://i.imgur.com/zUng6z2.png. I'm going to try to fix it, but it's working so it's no longer a huge problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, that's because the input is not child of the #range...wait a sec I'll made the adjustment in the answer

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking your time to fix it but it's still not working: http://i.imgur.com/uQ368vD.png . But hey, don't worry about it. Thank you again.

Comment: At this point it shouldn't be difficult to make it work! Cheers!

Comment: I finally figured it out. The problem was not in the JS, it was in the HTML: `$iterator = -1;` and that solved the problem.